# How to include HTML5 DOCTYPE in HTTP response

Tags: basex

When using BaseX for developing a web application, I'd like to return HTML and include the DOCTYPE that is typical for HTML5, namely `<!DOCTYPE html>`  I've noticed that if I set up a RESTXQ function and include the `%output:method('html')` annotation, there is no default DOCTYPE. If the function returns a sequence where the first item is the string `"<!DOCTYPE html>"` and the second is an `<html>` element, the web server escapes the angle brackets as `&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;`  Is there a way to disable character escaping? If I include `%output:doctype-system('html')` then the web server provides `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "html">` which isn't quite right. Is there a way to suppress `SYSTEM "html"`?

I'm not seeing anything on the RESTXQ page of the BaseX documentation about using the HTML5 DOCTYPE, and the draft RESTXQ spec I found at http://exquery.github.io/exquery/exquery-restxq-specification/restxq-1.0-specification.html doesn't mention DOCTYPE at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to output the result as HTML5, which can be done with the `html-version` serialization parameter:

```
declare 
  %rest:path('/test')
  %output:method('html')
  %output:html-version('5')
function local:test() {
  <html>Welcome</html>
};
```

Comment: Thanks, Christian! This is exactly what I needed.